# How do I pass the contents of a file as a command line parameter

Tags: bash, cat, arguments

I am storing a file path in a file and need to pass the *contents* of that file as an argument to a shell script, specifically Maven, something like so:

```
mvn -Dvar_name=(contents of file)
```

Would this work:

```
mvn -Dvar_name=(cat /path/to/file)
```

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done using command substitution, like so:

```
mvn -Dvar_name="$(cat /path/to/file)" # POSIX
mvn -Dvar_name="$(</path/to/file)"    # bash
```

This has a notable caveat though: all trailing newlines are stripped. If that doesn't matter, though, then that should work.

If you really just want to read one line, you could use `read` instead, like so:

```
IFS= read -r line < /path/to/file
mvn -Dvar_name="$line"
```

Answer (score 7):

For command substitution, you need to use `$()` or backticks ``.

It is also important that you quote the substitution, or it will expand into multiple arguments if the file contains more than one word. Here are some examples:

```
mvn -Dvar_name="$(< /path/to/file)" # bash

mvn -Dvar_name="$(cat /path/to/file)" # POSIX
```